# jqgrid sort icon on columns are not reset after trigger('reloadGrid') call

Tags: jqgrid

Please see the sample code below.

- Initially the grid comes up with no sort icon in any of the grid column headers - good.
- Click on 'Client' column header to sort the grid.
- Click on REFRESH button. It calls grid.trigger('reloadGrid').
- The grid is reloaded but sort icon on 'Client' header is still there. - not so good.

`

```
  $(function() {
     var mydata = [  
            {id:"1", name:"test",       amount:"200"},  
            {id:"2", name:"test2",      amount:"300"},  
            {id:"3", name:"F",          amount:"400"},  
            {id:"4", name:"test4",      amount:"200"},  
            {id:"5", name:"test5",      amount:"300"},  
            {id:"6", name:"test6",      amount:"400"},  
            {id:"7", name:"test7",      amount:"200"},  
            {id:"8", name:"test8",      amount:"300"},  
            {id:"9", name:"test9",      amount:"400"},  
            {id:"10",name:"test10",     amount:"500"},  
            {id:"11",name:"F",          amount:"500"},  
            {id:"12",name:"test11",     amount:"500"},  
            {id:"13", name:"test",      amount:"200"},  
            {id:"14", name:"O",         amount:"200"}  
 ];  
 jQuery("#list").jqGrid({           
        datatype: "local",  
        data: mydata,  
        width: 700,  
        loadComplete: function() {
            $(this).setGridParam({sortname: 'id'});
        },  
                    colNames:['Inv No','Client', 'Amount'],  
        colModel:[
            {name:'id',index:'id', width:65, sorttype:'int', searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','lt','le','gt','ge']}},  
            {name:'name',index:'name', width:100, searchoptions:{dataUrl:'/api/domains/producttypedomain'}},  
            {name:'amount',index:'amount', sorttype:'int', width:80, align:"right"}
        ],  
        rowNum:100, 
        pager: '#pager',            
        height:'auto',  
        viewrecords: true,  
        rownumbers: true,  
        gridview : true,            
        caption:"Advanced Search Example"
    });
    jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',  
    {
        edit:false,add:false,del:false,search:true,refresh:true
    },  
    {}, // edit options
    {}, // add options
    {}, //del options
    {
        multipleSearch:true, overlay:false,  recreateFilter:true            
    } // search options
    );
});
$(function() {
    $('#refresh-btn').click(function() {
        jQuery("#list").trigger('reloadGrid');          
    });
});
```

`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want that the sort icon will be not seen you can do this with

```
$("span.s-ico",jQuery("#list").grid.hDiv).hide();
```

Unsorted grid (`sortname:''`) is not the best choice in the most situations. So I recommend you to choose some column like 'id' for the data sorting. If you do want to have sorted data unsorted you have to set `sortname:''` parameter before the grid reload. So the function executed on click of your '#refresh-btn' button should be about the following

```
$('#refresh-btn').click(function() {
    var myGrid = jQuery("#list");
    $("span.s-ico",myGrid[0].grid.hDiv).hide(); // hide sort icons
    myGrid.setGridParam({sortname: ''}).trigger('reloadGrid');
});
```

What you want to do in the `loadComplete` am am not sure. Changing of `sortname` parameter on the place is too late.

You can see modified version of your code [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/NoSortIcon.htm). I change the order of some of the first items in the `mydata` array to show more clear that after the loading the data will be shown in the unsorted order.

I recommend you to remove Reload button from the grid navigator bar or to add [custom button](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_buttons) with look like "Reload" button and do what you really want to have.

Comment: It almost works. I had to add another line to make it work: myGrid[0].p.lastsort=-1.

Answer (score 1):

With version 4.6.0 of jqGrid this worked for me:

```
$('.s-ico').hide();
```